# Computing $H^1$ in Galois cohomology

Tags: galois-cohomology

I'm trying to learn the basics of Galois cohomology. If $k$ is a perfect field and $k^s$ is a separable closure, and $A$ is a finite group, how do you compute $H^1(\text{Gal}(k^s/k),A)=H^1(k,A)$?

Comment: Is the action on $A$ trivial? If so you're asking for homomorphisms from the absolute Galois group to $A$ and I don't know what there is to say about this in general without more information about one or the other.